# convert string/list into a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a little new to Python. I have multiple lists which look like the following:

Data:

```
(5300,
 53,
 1290,
 '`Tiytr`',
 '`professional`',
 1,
 3,
 datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 17, 0, 0))
```

They come stores as the following:

```
((63, 65, 1200, '`Jsalem`', '`professional`', 2, 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 19, 0, 0)), (70, 71, 1175, '`Cme`', '`professional`', 1, 0, datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 12, 0, 0)), (90, 55, 1100, '`Jerusalem`', '`professional`', 2, 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 20, 0, 0))
```

How can I convert these into a `pandas` dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert it into list and then pass it to `pandas.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime

x = ((63, 65, 1200, '`Jsalem`', '`professional`', 2, 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 19, 0, 0)), 
          (70, 71, 1175, '`Cme`', '`professional`', 1, 0, datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 12, 0, 0)), 
          (90, 55, 1100, '`Jerusalem`', '`professional`', 2, 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 20, 0, 0)))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(x))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0   1     2            3               4  5  6          7          8                                                                       
0  63  65  1200     `Jsalem`  `professional`  2  1 2018-10-13 2015-10-19                                                                       
1  70  71  1175        `Cme`  `professional`  1  0 2018-10-13 2018-10-12                                                                       
2  90  55  1100  `Jerusalem`  `professional`  2  1 2018-10-13 2015-10-20
```

Comment: Thanks! this works on this small sample but when I run it on the whole sample I get the following `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` - I will try to find the list which is causing the error and update the data

Comment: possible that your data structure is not the same as provided in sample data.